# Implementing Drag and Drop of a UIImageView using UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, xamarin.ios, gestures

I'm implementing a UILongPressGestureRecognizer that will allow the user to long press on an ImageView and then drag the image somewhere else.  Once the long press begins, I scale the view to indicate that dragging is ready and the user then can drag.  This is accomplished by updating the ImageViews frame each time the selector gets called with a change state.  This works perfectly but I would like to create a copy of the view and add it to a parent view on the begin state and then continue updating the copy's frame in the parent view.  I want to do this to eliminate any problems with dragging from scrollviews.  I can't seem to get the logic correct in the HandleChangeState method though.  The copy just doesn't drag correctly.

Any ideas?

Some of the code is just there because I'm trying to make a more generic UILongPressGestureRecognizer for UILabel and UIImageView but it doesn't pertain to this issue.

```
public class LearningViewLongPressGestureRecognizer : UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    {
        private UIImageView draggedImageView;
        private UILabel draggedLabel;
        private RectangleF originalFrame;       
        private UIView parentView;
        private DRAG_CONTENT_TYPE contentType;

        public enum DRAG_CONTENT_TYPE
        {
            UIIMAGEVIEW,
            UILabel
        }

        public static Selector LongPressSelector
        {
            get
            {
                return new Selector ("HandleLongPress");
            }
        }

        public LearningViewLongPressGestureRecognizer (UIView parent, DRAG_CONTENT_TYPE contentType)
        {
            this.contentType = contentType;
            this.AddTarget(this, LongPressSelector);
            this.Delegate = new LongPressRecognizerDelegate();
            this.parentView = parent;
        }

        [Export("HandleLongPress")]
        public void HandleLongPress(UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("HandleLongPress Called.");
            switch (recognizer.State)
            {
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
                Console.WriteLine ("HandleLongPress Began.");
                HandleBeginState(recognizer);
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                Console.WriteLine ("HandleLongPress Changed.");
                HandleChangedState(recognizer);
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled:
                Console.WriteLine ("HandleLongPress Canceled.");
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
                Console.WriteLine ("HandleLongPress Ended.");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine ("HandleLongPress Default.");
                break;
            }
        }

        private void HandleBeginState(UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {
            this.originalFrame = this.View.Frame;                       

            if (contentType == DRAG_CONTENT_TYPE.UIIMAGEVIEW)
            {
                draggedImageView = new UIImageView();
                draggedImageView.Image = ((UIImageView)this.View).Image;    
                draggedImageView.Frame = this.View.Frame;

                //Change the view scale to indicate to the user that the view is selected and ready for dragging.
                draggedImageView.Transform *= CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);

                parentView.AddSubview(draggedImageView);
                parentView.BringSubviewToFront(draggedImageView);                   
            }                               
        }

        private void HandleChangedState(UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {           
            PointF currentLocationOfTouchInParentView = recognizer.LocationInView(draggedImageView);//recognizer.TranslationInView(this.View);
            PointF deltaFromOriginal = new PointF(currentLocationOfTouchInParentView.X - originalFrame.X, currentLocationOfTouchInParentView.Y - originalFrame.Y);

            RectangleF newFrame = draggedImageView.Frame;
            newFrame.Offset(deltaFromOriginal.X, deltaFromOriginal.Y);
            draggedImageView.Frame = newFrame;
        }

        private void HandleCanceledState(UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {

        }

        private void HandleEndedState(UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {

        }

        protected class LongPressRecognizerDelegate : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
        {
            public override bool ShouldReceiveTouch (UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UITouch touch)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my calculations issue.  I needed to take the delta of the original touch location that began the gesture and the current touch location within the parent view and then add that offset to the dragged view frame.  Below is my solution.

```
private void HandleBeginState(UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {
            this.originalFrame = this.View.Frame;                       
            this.originalTouchLocation = recognizer.LocationInView(parentView);

            if (contentType == DRAG_CONTENT_TYPE.UIIMAGEVIEW)
            {
                draggedImageView = new UIImageView();
                draggedImageView.Image = ((UIImageView)this.View).Image;    
                draggedImageView.Frame = new RectangleF(originalFrame.X, originalFrame.Y, originalFrame.Size.Width, originalFrame.Size.Height);

                parentView.AddSubview(draggedImageView);
                parentView.BringSubviewToFront(draggedImageView);   

                //Change the view scale to indicate to the user that the view is selected and ready for dragging.
                draggedImageView.Transform *= CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);
            }                               
        }

        private void HandleChangedState(UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {           
            PointF currentLocationOfTouchInParentView = recognizer.LocationInView(parentView);
            PointF deltaFromOriginalTouch = new PointF(currentLocationOfTouchInParentView.X - originalTouchLocation.X, currentLocationOfTouchInParentView.Y - originalTouchLocation.Y);

            RectangleF newFrame = originalFrame;
            newFrame.Offset(deltaFromOriginalTouch.X, deltaFromOriginalTouch.Y);
            draggedImageView.Frame = newFrame;          
        }
```